# Picking cards from pack of $52$ cards

Tags: probability

In a pack of cards there are $52$ cards, Adam takes $10$ cards from the pack and then put them back and mixes the whole pack, then he gives the pack  to Daniel, Daniel takes $15$ cards.

$(1.)$  Find the probability that **all** the cards that Adam took are among the cards that Daniel took.

$(2.)$ Find the probability  that there is **at least one** card that Adam took  among the cards that Daniel took.

$(3.)$ Find the probability  that there are **exactly 5** cards that Adam took  among the cards that Daniel took

---

**My attempt:**

$(1.)$ Let $A$ be the event that all the cards that Adam took are among the cards that Daniel took

$$|A|=\binom{52}{10}$$

Let $\Omega$ be the group of all the possibilities of goups with $15$ cards

$$|\Omega|=\binom{52}{15}
\Longrightarrow\mathbb{P}=\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{\binom{52}{10}}{\binom{52}{15}}\approx 0.00353 $$

$(2.)$ Let $B$ be the event at least one card that Adam took  among the cards that Daniel took, and let $\overline{B}$ be the event  there isn't card that Adam took  among the cards that Daniel took.

$$|\overline B|=\binom {42}{15}\Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(\overline{B})=\frac{|\overline{B}|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{\binom{42}{15}}{\binom{52}{15}}\approx 0.022\\
\Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(B)=1-\mathbb{P}(\overline{B})\approx 0.977$$

$(3.)$  $$\mathbb{P}(C)=\frac{\binom{52}{10}\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{52}{15}}\approx 0.889$$

This is correct?

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{P}(C) = \frac{\binom{\color{red}{42}}{10}\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{52}{15}}$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No

Comment: The reason I asked the question is that there are $42$ cards Daniel did not take, from which Adam must take $10$ if he takes exactly $5$ of the ten that Daniel did take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(1)$ Daniel must pick the remaining $5$ cards from the remaining $42$ cards. So the required probability is $${\binom{42}{5}\over\binom{52}{15}}$$

For $(3)$ Daniel must pick the remaining $10$ cards from the remaining $42$ cards.So the required probability is $${\binom{10}{5}\binom{42}{10}\over\binom{52}{15}}$$

Comment: $(2.)$ is correct?